# Reading output from Powershell takes much time to execute

Tags: java, performance

So, I wrote this code on java and it's taking some 6 second times to execute and give output. As I am not from coding background I was expecting if someone from this expert's group could help me optimize this little.
Below is my code also the PowerShell command runs within seconds. only this while loop is taking much time.

What I want to achieve is just get the list of drives which is HDD and print it.

```
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe Get-Partition -disknumber 1 | select DriveLetter");
BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
String line1 = "";
ArrayList<String> hddList = new ArrayList<String>();
while ((line1 = in.readLine()) != null) {
    if (!line1.trim().isEmpty()) {
        if (line1.contains("HDD")) {
            hddList.add(line1.replaceAll(" +", "#").split("#")[0]+"#"+"HDD");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: how many iterations must it do?

Comment: depends on number of outputs from PowerShell command. I need all drives.

Comment: Are you sure the problem it is in the loop, and not in the previous process of open the powershell? Because the loop doesn't look bad.

Comment: Previous PowerShell command gets executed within few milliseconds. But When it enters While loop its takes 2 second to execute. I tried to divide all the while loop part and found in.readLine() is taking approx 2 sec time. Any alternate solution for that ?

Comment: Ok not any problem at all, at the beginning I was thinking the time was too much high, but 2s is the time for the BufferedReader, you don't have any way to improve that, maybe if you can use `FileChannel`instead of BufferedReader, but 2s is average on that class

Comment: Actually, I have to execute 3 PowerShell command in a row including this so overall it is taking approx. 6-7 sec of time and that's what my main problem is.

Comment: BTW, as of `Java 18`, the string version of `Runtime.getRuntime().exec` has been deprecated.  The `String array` version should be used with the array holding each of the arguments.  E.g. `Runtime.getRuntime().exec("powershell.exe Get-Partition -disknumber 1 | select DriveLetter".split("\\s+"));`

Comment: Also, within the `powershell program` itself, it takes 6 seconds for my invocation to come back with the information sans the pipe.  This is probably related to Windows response time and not Java.  I am runing a quad core i7 processor, using Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an [xy-problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378), as you can easily get the drive letters in Java like

```java
List<String> driveLetters = new ArrayList<>();
for(Path r: FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories()) {
    String s = r.toString();
    if(s.length() == 3 && s.charAt(1) == ':') {
        driveLetters.add(s.substring(0, 1));
    }
}
```

since Java 7. This needs no interprocess communication and hence, has no such latency problems.

If you want to limit the result to fixed HDDs, you can use something like

```java
List<String> driveLetters = new ArrayList<>();
for(Path r: FileSystems.getDefault().getRootDirectories()) {
    String s = r.toString();
    if(s.length() == 3 && s.charAt(1) == ':') try {
        FileStore store = Files.getFileStore(r);
        if(!Boolean.TRUE.equals(store.getAttribute("volume:isRemovable"))
        && !Boolean.TRUE.equals(store.getAttribute("volume:isCdrom"))) {
            driveLetters.add(s.substring(0, 1));
        }
    }
    catch(IOException ex) {} // no media in drive, obviously not an HDD then
}
```

Comment: This looks good . Thanks for the reply also can you tell me what string to pass in `store.getAttribute("")`  if I also want to list my SSD and HDD both ?

Comment: This should already include HDDs and SSDs in the result (unless they are mounted as removable devices). Operating systems rarely differentiate between these two. I also used the term “fixed HDDs” in the broader sense of all non-removable mass storage devices.

Answer (score 0):

As I said in my comments, I believe the issue is with the execution of the `powerShell` and not Java. See how quickly the following runs using the `cmd.exe`.
Here, all I'm doing is a directory listing and replacing `<DIR>` as though it was HDD.

```
        Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(
                "cmd.exe /c dir".split("\\s+"));
                        
        System.out.println(p);
        BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
                new java.io.InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        String line1 = "";
        List<String> hddList = new ArrayList<String>();
        while ((line1 = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line1);
            if (!line1.trim().isEmpty()) {
                if (line1.contains("<DIR>")) {
                    hddList.add(line1.replaceAll(" +", "#").split("#")[0] + "#"
                            + "HDD");
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println(hddList);
```

You might be able to run `cmd.exe` as administrator and use related privileged commands to get the disk information.  I have yet to determine how to do that without password input.

Comment: yes your code executed very fast. But in my case its the java code which is taking 2 sec of time and rest is executing fast . I will post my code and time it took to execute.  But before that i need your help to understand where i can post my new code again ? as in comments its not allowing me to do.

Comment: So you opened powershell and when the command was run it returned immediately?  When I did that it took 6 seconds.

Comment: Just edit your question and add the new code. Annotate it as such but don't remove the original.

Comment: Yes @WJS in PowerShell as well it replied withing milliseconds and in java as well it replies within milliseconds. May be because I am using PowerShell 7 and hexa core processor with 16GB RAM.

Comment: @vijaykumar The pre-test `!line1.trim().isEmpty()` wastes more resources than it saves, as `contains("<DIR>")` on a blank string is not more expensive than the pre-test itself. While `trim()` on a non-blank string may add additional costs but still requires the `contains` operation. Further `line1.replaceAll(" +", "#").split("#")[0] + "#" + "HDD"` makes multiple expensive detours to effectively make something like `line1.replaceFirst(" .*|$", "#HDD")` (or even `int ix = line1.indexOf(' '); hddList.add((ix < 0? line1: line1.substring(0, ix)) + "#HDD");` without regex).